# How to publish own npm module for ionic 2?

Tags: module, npm, ionic2

I would like to develop and publish a npm module and publish it. I have tried reading the content on the websites. I did not find any tutorial which will give me all insights and the best practices to be followed while creating a module as a plug and play component.

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Did you find any tutorials or help on this as I am looking to do the same?

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-module-template helped me

Comment: I would like to add this ["comments"](http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20170407-SharingIonic2CodeBetweenProjects.html) to the ionic-module-template mention by @k1dbl4ck

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems to be the very simple question, but I guess the second part of the question is more crucial. It would require applying your best experience.
Pls. refer below Links:

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules

https://github.com/mattdesl/module-best-practices